# Is it possible to migrate an answer from one question to another?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, deleted-answers

Is it possible to migrate an answer from one question to another question without losing reputation and comments. This happened to me recently whereby the OP had asked two questions and it turned out my answer was more aposite on their other question. The questions were quite close in nature and were asking similar things, which is how the mixup occurred. I didn't realise the other question existed otherwise I would have posted there initially.

Hence I deleted my original and reposted it on the other question. Now in doing so I lost any votes (there were none but that's not the point) plus some rather useful comments. If this is not possible could migration of an **entire** answer, including rep plus comments be a feature request. Maybe others can imagine a scenario where this feature could be useful.

Comment: I believe you can flag a moderator for possible migration, in the case that the question you answered was closed as a duplicate of another. If they are not deemed duplicates, then you are free to undelete your answer.  But try not to practice duplicate answering either.  I suspect, if your answer applied also to an earlier question, you should be voting to close it as a duplicate, and not answering.  Since it seems you did not know it was a duplicate, there is no harm in asking for the migration of your answer, provided the question you answered is closed as a dupe.

Comment: @amWhy thanks I didn't know that. I did think of the duplicate situation, but was not sure. In the end they asked two different questions which turned out to be intimately linked in their solutions. I think they (maybe) should have been asked as one question seeing as there was overlap, but as they asked two different things I left matters as they were.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to merge one question-thread  Q1 into another one Q2.

This will move *all* answers and comments on Q1 to Q2, and effectively delete Q1.

For further details see:

[What is a "merged" question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158066/what-is-a-merged-question)

Beyond that neither posts nor comments can be moved around (except for migrating the whole thread to another site, but that's unrelated).

Comment: that's great, thank you. What of my specific case though, the linked you give to merge question deletes Q1, and merges Q1 and Q2, whereas I merely want to migrate my answer to Q2 and leave Q1 alone.